# Pass selected radio button value from view to model and/or controller MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I am trying to use a percent value selected in a view to set the 'discount' property in a model. The percent value is selected by selecting a radio button that represents an available discount for a product. How do I get the value from the selected radio button and set the model accordingly? Do I have to use the database/controllers at all?

```
<br />
<div>
    <strong>Discounts:</strong>

    @foreach (var discount in Model.Product.DiscountsAvailable)
    {
        <br/>
        @Html.RadioButton("Product.Discount", discount, true, 
             new { Id = string.Format("{0}-{1}", Model.Product.CourseId, 
                   discount.DiscountId) })
        @discount.Description
        @discount.Percentage
    }

    <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Provide same name to all the radio buttons of the discount and at the back end fetch them as you did to others. You will get you required selected discount.

Comment: Thanks Purushottam... how do I fetch them at the back end?

Comment: The same way you get the values of input box.